# Clustering Mapbox Android SymbolManager annotations

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I'm in the process of improving the usability of an Android application that I'm working on. The application utilises the [Mapbox SDK (Android) 7.0.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/android) for core mapping functionality, with the [Mapbox Annotations 0.4.0](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/tree/master/plugin-annotation) plugin used for placing markers/symbols on the map (as per [official Mapbox documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/annotations/) regarding the deprecation of the existing method of adding markers to a `MapboxMap` instance using `mapboxMap.addMarker(...)`).

My implementation makes use of a [SymbolManager](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/plugins/annotation/0.4.0/index.html?com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/annotation/SymbolManager.html) to bulk import annotation markers/symbols using a technique very similar to [this official example](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/testapp/activity/annotation/BulkSymbolActivity.java). This works just fine, however I'd like to improve this by having my annotation markers/symbols *cluster* in a manner similar to [this other official example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/).

The problem I see here is that annotation marker/symbol clustering relies on adding/removing [SymbolLayer](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/7.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/layers/SymbolLayer.html) objects ([in the example linked above](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/symbol-layer-clustering/)). I'm having very little luck finding information on how this functionality might be achieved using a [SymbolManager](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/plugins/annotation/0.4.0/index.html?com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/annotation/SymbolManager.html) object instead.

Is there a way to achieve annotation marker/symbol clustering similar to that of the aforementioned (`SymbolLayer`) example, using a `SymbolManager` instead?

Any help with this would be immensely appreciated!

---

The closest information that I could find on the topic was [this outstanding issue](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/issues/648) in the Mapbox Annotation plugin GitHub repository which makes references to what could be the functionality I'm seeking, flagged for future development.

Comment: Hey Tom, great to see you are using the annotations plugin! As you already discovered this is a feature we will be adding in the near future but isn't supported out of the box for now. You can however, easily add this yourself! Under the hood the annotation plugin uses a GeoJsonSource and SymbolLayer. This combination allows to add clusters as shown in this example https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/style/GeoJsonClusteringActivity.java#L89-L100

Comment: Many thanks for the guidance @Tobrun! I'll give this a shot, and see how I go. Thanks again!

Comment: The Link is dead, any updates on this? @Tobrun

Comment: @SteMa I tracked down the up-to-date link for the stopgap solution that Tobrun offered: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/blob/master/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/style/GeoJsonClusteringActivity.java#L92-L107 I hope that helps!